# Ignore the mouse hover event of a parent with a child in the same class css

Tags: html, css

I want to represent nested sets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NestedSetModel.svg)

Having the following html structure

```
<div class="circle">
    <div class="nodeText">Clothing</div>
    <span class="lft">1</span>
    <span class="rgt">22</span>
    <div class="circle" id="node2">
    <div class="nodeText">Men's</div>
    <span class="lft">2</span>
    <span class="rgt">9</span>
    </div>
    <div class="circle" id="node3" >
        <div class="nodeText" >Women's</div>
    <span class="lft">10</span>
    <span class="rgt">21</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS (at least what I think is important to the question)

```
.circle {
background-color: blue;
    margin:10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    z-index: inherit;
}

.circle:HOVER{
background-color: red;
}
```

The behavior I want, is that when I mouse over a div with class "circle" (in this example "Men's" or "Women's") I change the background color of these, but not the parent div 'Clothing'

Answer (score 0):

I change

```
.circlr:hover
```

to

```
.circlr .circle:hover
```

This is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/sechou/9eNuN/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shih-En Chou, Thanks for the reply, but that only works on two levels, which happens if I need more levels of children

Comment: It works for muitiple level. Can you give the example of more levels

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rDmqg/)**

I have an extension to inner class name with `.circle`

Parent Class name will be `class="circle"` while inner class name for men or women will be `class="circle color"`

Go through code to understand it properly.

Perhaps the most powerful aspect of class selectors is that multiple classes can be applied to one HTML element. For example, you may wish to use two rules on one particular element like this:

```
<p class="big indent">

.big { font-weight: bold; }
.indent { padding-left: 2em;}
```